# How to identify which value in a HashMap gives a true and then do something with that?

Tags: java, lambda

I wrote a lambda expression in Java that takes the key and the value from a LinkedHashMap (both the key and the value being of a custom object) . The Lambda expression takes the key (which contains a String name) and the value (which is a condition, either win, loose or draw and of type enum) and then  compares the key and value to a preset condition(either win, loose or draw, again of type enum). If the value is the same as the preset condition, a boolean true is returned, otherwise a false is returned.

```
`for (Wedstrijd wedstrijd : wedstrijden)    

wedstrijd.getVoorspelling()
                        .forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("User: " + key + " guessed " + value.equals(wedstrijd.getUitslag())));
```

This works as I want it to work and returns, for example (console output):

```
The Preset condition is:
WIN

User
"David: guessed" true
"Andrew: guessed" false
```

Now I want to give the user points if they guessed correctly. So if the boolean is true. This needs to happen every time the for each loop runs.
I have been at this all day and I can't think of a way on how to go about this.
Is this possible by using the lambda that I wrote earlyer? Or do I need to build a seperate method for this? If so, how would i go about this?

Comment: What is the sample data and the expected result?

Comment: I have no sample data. What I want is to add the points to an Integer which is set in an object.

final static Integer score = 0;
is the base value of the Integer and for every right guess of the user the specific instance of that score that belong to that user needs get an extra 3 points.

Comment: You can have a code block in your lambda ? `(key, value) -> {many statements}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following

```
wedstrijd.getVoorspelling()
                        .forEach((key, value) -> {
     many statements as mentioned above
}));
```

or

```
wedstrijd.getVoorspelling()
                        .forEach((key, value) -> anotherMethod(key,value)        
));

anotherMethod(key,value){
   logic here
}
```

Comment: But I'm having trouble adding to the unique key.




 If I do a for each loop, like this;


`public void addPoints() {
  for(Wedstrijd wedstrijd:wedstrijden) {
   wedstrijd.getVoorspelling()
      .forEach((key, value) -> {
          boolean matches = value.equals(wedstrijd.getUitslag());
          if (matches) {
           for (Deelnemer deelnemer:deelnemers) {
            deelnemer.setScore(deelnemer.getScore() + 3);
            System.out.println(deelnemer.getScore());
           }
`
I just adds the score to each and every user.

Answer (score 0):

```
wedstrijd.getVoorspelling()
    .forEach((key, value) -> {
        boolean matches = value.equals(wedstrijd.getUitslag();
        System.out.printf("User: %s guessed %s%n", key, matches));
        if (matches) {
            ... give points
        }
     });
```

I think the problems stems from the new syntax variations. Instead of `System.println(...)` one can add `{ ... }`.